# Can a Windows hypervisor running inside Linux access Windows-only drivers?

Tags: linux, container, 3d

Suppose you have a Linux as host OS. Within a container you run a Windows hypervisor.

Will that Windows hypervisor have access to Windows-only 3D accelerated drivers that Linux doesn't support?

Comment: This question in not clear. What is "container as host"? What containerisation software? What hypervisor?

Comment: if you *only* have a linux container, meaning you don't own/have no control on the actual linux host and hardware, don't expect you can run virtualization in it. Then of course if you could, that would be a *linux* hypervisor, to run a windows *VM*.

Comment: Ok I simplified the question.